# Почему в этом предложении ставится запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп, егэ

Торжок расположен сравнительно недалеко от Москвы, и поэтому у вышивальщиц всегда были богатые заказчики и покупатели.

Это предложение из 21-го задания ЕГЭ по русскому языку. Дело в том, что по ответам запятая в этом предложении ставится не по причине ССП (сложносочинённого предложения) и СПП (сложноподчинённого предложения). Меня очень мучает этот вопрос: так по какой же причине здесь ставится запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Я видела это задание в Сети, но в этом предложении **нет наречия "поэтому":**

(1)Шить золотом стали с тех пор, как удалось получить тонкую золотую нить. (2)Известно, что уже в XVII–XVIII веках этим промыслом занимались многие вышивальщицы в городе Торжке. **(3)Торжок расположен сравнительно недалеко от Москвы, и у вышивальщиц всегда были богатые заказчики и покупатели.** (4)Мастерицы украшали богатой вышивкой царские и боярские одежды, часто дополняя вышивку жемчугом и драгоценными камнями. (5)Ткани, по которым вышивали женщины, были, как правило, плотными, тяжёлыми. (6)Женский труд был очень дешёвым. (7)Работа вышивальщиц оказалась трудной, а денег за неё платили мало. (8)Со временем одежда стала дешевле и проще, однако золотошвеи из Торжка не бросали своего мастерства.

https://examer.ru/ege_po_russkomu_yaziku/2023/zadanie_21/task/988qj

В вузовской грамматике  **союзное соединение "и поэтому"** относится **к ССП,** здесь И сочинительный союз, а наречие "поэтому" является дополнительным структурным элементом. Единственным официальным союзом для СПП с придаточным **следствия является союз ТАК ЧТО**. При отсутствии союза И (только наречие "поэтому") это было бы **БСП**. Но в школе могут быть **свои правила.**

В любом случае здесь какая-то **неточность.** К сожалению, я не могу посмотреть ответы на этом ресурсе, там надо регистрироваться.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (материал из Сети о наречии "поэтому")

Это, кажется, уже школьная программа.

**Союз или союзное слово**

Как самостоятельная часть речи, наречие **не может быть союзом.** Нельзя его назвать и **союзным словом,** ведь в отличие от союзного слова, слово «поэтому» можно убрать из сложного предложения без потери смысла.

Наречие «поэтому» лишь **условно выполняет функцию** союза следствия или союзного слова. Оно соединяет части сложного предложения со значением причинно-следственной обусловленности, но при этом сохраняет все признаки своей части речи и связи с другими членами предложения.

**Примеры:** «Мне важно знать твое мнение, поэтому я и спрашиваю тебя». «Приближалась осень, поэтому дни становились все холоднее».

Это слово может использоваться в качестве связующего звена и **в сложноподчиненном, и в сложносочиненном предложении.** В первом случае обычно употребляется одиночный союз «поэтому», а во втором — его сочетание с сочинительным союзом (**«и поэтому», «но поэтому», «а поэтому»**).

Пример: «На улице было сыро и холодно, **поэтому** мы не пошли на прогулку».

Пример: «Стипендия была маленькой, **и поэтому** студенты старались подрабатывать в свободное время».

Comment: Это, конечно, просто вопросы строительства терминологии, и можно считать ‟и поэтому” как сложносочинённым, так и сложноподчинённым, но мне кажется более правильным считать этот союз сложноподчинённым, так как здесь нет равноправности, как в сложносочинённых, а следственные  отношения главного и придаточного. Что значит ‟Единственным официальным союзом для СПП с придаточным следствия является союз ТАК ЧТО”? Я просто навскидку назову пару штук: ‟потому”, ‟поэтому”, ‟вследствие чего”, ‟в связи с чем”, ‟оттого”.  В большинстве словарей ‟поэтому”, потому” также являются союзом, как и наречием.

Comment: Вот, например, первый попавшийся словарь Ожогова — https://slovarozhegova.ru/word.php?wordid=23220

Comment: Лингвисты — удивительны! Есть 100500 слов, как ‟что”, ‟когда”, ‟потому”, ‟сколько”, которые могут быть местоимениями или наречия, но также могут связывать предложения в СПП, и мы возьмём слово ‟поэтому”, которое точно такое же как все эти 100500 слов, а потом по какой-то совершенно удивительной, известной только богу причине не будем считать это слово таким же, как те 100500.

Comment: Грамматика наука точная, не надо ее изучать по ТОЛКОВЫМ словарям. Я тоже использую уже устоявшуюся терминологию вузовского уровня, так как в академической грамматике часто описываются мнения нескольких школ, материалы, находящиеся в процессе развития, новых разработок и т.д. Я цитирую учебник для педвузов как наиболее удобный – там нет школьного упрощения, которое часто препятствует ясному пониманию предмета, в то же время он достаточно прост для усвоения обычной аудиторией.

Comment: (1) Вследствие чего, в связи с чем – это присоединительные союзные слова в СПП с придаточными присоединительными (на это указывают падежные формы местоимения «что», обращенные к предыдущей части предложения). 
(2) Я допускаю, что «поэтому» в школьной практике  для упрощения может считаться подчинительным союзом со значением следствия.

Comment: (3) Но сочетание «и поэтому» становится противоречивым, гибридным. На первом месте сочинительный союз И, который сам по себе способен обозначить следственные отношения (наречие «поэтому» дополнительно конкретизирует его). Это видно из того, что в оригинальном тексте его вообще не было. Поэтому сочинительный союз И следует считать главным (это ССП), что и указано в вузовской грамматике. В школе (тем более на экзаменах) такое сочетание нежелательно включать в предложение для разбора. Так откуда такой союз там появился?  Составители перестарались?

Comment: Чем считать ‟поэтому” это вопрос морфологии, морфология занимается сегментацией слов на подсовокупности. Промежуточные вопросы строительства терминологии о  сегментации слов на подсовокупности не имеют ничего общего с какой-либо точностью, они могут разрешаться хоть подбрасыванием монетки. (1) Я вообще не вижу смысла в том, что вы написали про союзы ‟вследствие чего” и ‟в связи с чем”, уж извините. (3) То что кто-то не считает ‟поэтому” обычным союзом в СПП следствия, можно объяснить только тем, что какой-то авторитетный лингвист написался, написал статью, не внеся ‟поэтому” в союзы, а потом

Comment: это вошло в какие-то пособия. Это вообще никак нельзя иначе объяснить. Откуда там взялось слово ‟поэтому”? Какая разница? Предложение с ‟поэтому” грамматически верно, поэтому можно рассматривать его.

Comment: Простое предложение: *Он упал и поэтому не пришёл.*

Comment: Почему "поэтому" не является союзом в грамматике (не в школе), вы можете подумать сами или посмотреть в учебниках по грамматике, я же не имею особого желания вам это рассказывать (это долго и бесполезно). Предложение из пособия является ССП согласно вузовскому учебнику. В школе вроде бы тоже ССП, например: Это слово может использоваться в качестве связующего звена и в СПП, и в ССП. В первом случае обычно употребляется одиночный союз «поэтому», а во втором — его сочетание с сочинительным союзом («и поэтому», «но поэтому», «а поэтому»). https://barahola.ru/stati/kogda-stavitsya-zapyataya/

Comment: Он упал и поэтому не пришёл.   Здесь наречие "поэтому" дифференцирует однородное сказуемое,  таких вариантов в разными словами много.

Comment: @oleedd Это хороший аргумент, чтобы считать ‟и поэтому” сложносочинённым союзом. Я так и буду делать впредь. Если бы было: ‟Он упал, поэтому и не пришёл”, то это уже был бы сложноподчинённый союз и придаточное. Наречием ‟поэтому” я считаю в предложениях типа: ‟Вот поэтому мы и расстались!”, то есть где нет связи предложения в составном предложении.

Comment: Каждый имеет право считать что угодно чем угодно, но при этом желательно иметь ссылку на авторитетный источник. Если хотите, чтобы вас другие слушали.

Comment: Ещё раз, ‟поэтому” может быть и наречием, и союзом. В предложения типа: ‟Он мало учился, поэтому его не взяли в академию” — ‟поэтому” является союзом хоть в школьной, хоть в университетской программе.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на университетскую программу.

Comment: Ссылку я не буду искать. Я уже дал ссылку на Ожогова. Больше я не буду тратиться время, доказывая то, что написано в почти в любом словаре и должно быть очевидно любому идиоту. Тот же Ожогов авторитетнее любого автора вузовского учебника, этого уже достаточно.

Comment: Понятненько.  Только на ненормированную лексику не переходите, пожалуйста. А я вот решила потратить время (в издании 2013 года такая же информация) Учебник для педвузов, стр. 234 БСП НЕОДНОРОДНОГО СОСТАВА Структурные элементы:   местоименные наречия потому,ПОЭТОМУ, оттого, частицы так, так и, вот и во второй части. https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf

Comment: Ссылка нерабочая.

Comment: И что если так. Так как лингвисты недоумки, то они думают, что подобные вопросы являются неким научным поискам, когда же такие вопросы просто являются вопросом построения терминологии, которую нужно потом согласовать и пользоваться для формирования утверждений для себя и разговора на эти темы. В итоге получаются такого рода разночтения, когда люди считают по-разному какие-то подобные промежуточные вопросы. Просто нужно понимать, что это не вопросы познания языка, а вопросы строительства терминологии, и что разные лингвисты могут пользоваться разной терминологией об этом.

Comment: Ожогов пользовался такой же терминологией, как и я, а вот эти люди, что писали этот учебник, нагородили каких-то терминов про ‟структурные элементы БСП”, ‟БСП неоднородного состава”. Нагородили какой-то срани, но пожалуйста, если кто-то выстраивает какую-то кривую терминологию, то это его проблемы.

Comment: Это уже не научный поиск, а учебник, который изучают студенты, причем не филологи, а будущие учителя. Последний толковый словарь (не грамматика) Ожегова под ред. Шведовой вышел:  21-е издание (1989).  А грамматика - это наиболее динамично развивающаяся наука и по точности она близка к математике.  А это уже кое-что значит и исключает свободное толкование  грамматических структур.

Comment: В Викисловаре написано, что ‟потому” это союз. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/потому#:~:text=Наречие%2C%20обстоятельственное%2C%20причины%2C%20также,-%20%5BТихонов%2C%201996%5D. Ещё раз, это вопрос морфологии, раздела, который занимается сегментацией слов на подсовокупности. Я не понимаю, о чём вы говорите. Грамматика это правила сочетания слов, о какой точности идёт речь, точности в чём? В данном случае мы видим, что какие-то лингвисты на основании буквально полубредовых, аморфных соображений выстроили в каком-то маленьком сегменте небольшие терминологические отличия, не имея каких-то обосно

Comment: ванных соображений или чего-то подобного. Невероятный прогресс относительно времени Ожогова!

Comment: @JimKorbett "Ож**е**гов"! Не очень вы его уважаете... Не придаточное, потому что можно оформить отдельным предложением и равносильно "из-за этого". Да, оно связывает предложения, но нет прямо подчинения. *Поэтому* — наречие, местоименное, указательное, обстоятельственное, причины, также **союзное слово**; неизменяемое. Союзное слово — это не союз, а слово, которое может выступать в роли союза.

Comment: От словаря к словарю и от учебника к учебнику одно и то же слово будет называться авторами то союзным словом, то союзом, так что это не важно. То как употребляют эти термины, делает их абсолютными синонимами.

Comment: Не очень понял объяснений про то, что это не придаточное. И с союзом ‟но”, и с союзом ‟и” иногда оформляется отдельным предложением.

Comment: @JimKorbett Вы не понимаете. Союз — это часть речи. Оно не зависит от того, где стоит слово. Союзное слово — это слово, являющееся другой частью речи, но оно может быть похожим на союз в определённых позициях. Ну так "и" и "но" — это сочинительные союзы, а не подчинительные (присоединяют придаточное).

Comment: Имею в виду то, что союз сочинительный, а не подчинительный.

Comment: Например, слово ‟и” может быть частицей. Почти все слова могут быть другими частями речи. И что, что он сочинительный? Что это вообще меняет?

Comment: @JimKorbett Это не тот случай. Частицей "и" является на самом деле, потому что у неё совсем другой смысл тогда. А наречия называть союзами можно весьма условно. Это союзные слова. Не зря же другой термин придумали.

Comment: Если разграничивать термины ‟союз” и ‟союзное слово”, то лучше это делать в таких ситуациях: ‟Я знаю, что произошло” и ‟Я знаю, что он не делал этого”. То есть когда ‟что” выполняет не только функцию соединения, а когда ещё и является местоимением.

Comment: Вот это бы имело бы смысл.

Comment: @JimKorbett Ну и этот случай туда же. Здесь это более важно. *Что это вообще меняет?* — вид предложения, это не придаточное (а вы так сказали).

Comment: Не понял. Слово ‟и” может быть частицей, а может быть союзом; ‟что” может быть местоимением, а может быть союзом — ‟Я знаю, что он придёт” . Так какая разница между ними? Ещё раз. Почему ‟что” является союзным словом? Если брать предложения, где ‟что” является также членом предложения — ‟Я знаю, что произошло”, то тогда понятно какая разница.

Comment: @JimKorbett С частицами другая история. К настоящему союзу нельзя задать вопрос (*почему? — поэтому*).

Answer (score 0):

В таком предложении: ‟Он не сделал работу, поэтому на него высыпали гору упрёков” — ‟поэтому” является союзом, но в сочетании с ‟и”, как в вашем предложении, сочетание ‟и” и ‟поэтому” считается сочетанием сложносочинённого союза ‟и” и местоименного наречия ‟поэтому”, поэтому в итоге причина запятой в сложносочинённом предложении с союзом ‟и”. Такой ответ, скорее всего, будет в ответах.